# Video player that allows HTML embedding for questions and other user interactions

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

I'm looking for a video player that allows HTML embedding for questions and other user interactions, to build an educacion site similar to Coursera. The idea is to allow pop-quiz and other material to show while doing the lectures.

Could you please suggest one that's suited for this, or if not possible, point me in the right direction on how to build it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[popcorn.js](http://popcornjs.org/) might be worth a look:

> Popcorn.js is an HTML5 media framework written in JavaScript for
>   filmmakers, web developers, and anyone who wants to create time-based
>   interactive media on the web.

I'd check out the [demos](http://popcornjs.org/demos) as some of them may be doing some of the things you want to do. I don't really have time to play with it at the moment, but [this one](http://katehudsondesign.com/demos/popcornmacbeth/), which attempts to teach Shakespeare by providing contemporary translations along with a video reading, looks like it might be interesting to you.